# Is it possible to open a new blank tab in the browser?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

The user himself will need to enter the URL, so I don't need to transfer any URL, just open a new blank tab in the default browser.

Comment: You could set the URL to chrome://newtab with the with this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: For most browsers, use `about:blank` as the address to get a blank page. Maybe this helps?

Comment: @Gabe Doesn't work at least on safari. I've tried `launch('chrome://newtab')` and `launch(Uri.parse('chrome://newtab').toString())`.

Comment: @mhutter Where can it be inserted?

Comment: you could try the `about:blank` passed in as the URL in url lancher as mhutter suggested.

Comment: @Gabe I tried, but also without a positive result.